# Using FastLink for Account Refresh and Edit

Tags: yodlee

We are trying to use Fastlink to provide instant refresh and account edit functions. This has not been successful as we keep getting "Problem updating account" FastLink UI.
[image: Fastlink error on Refresh or edit flow]

We do not want to use the ProviderAccount PUT API to trigger refresh as we want to stay away from providing login/MFA UI. FastLink has been very helpful in providing the account add function and we really want to leverage it for all the account related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following sample values in extraParams for refreshing or updating account.

Refresh Account:
String extraParams="flow=**refresh**&siteAccountId=10139794&callback=https://www.google.co.in";

Update Account:String extraParams = "flow=**edit**&siteAccountId=10139794&callback=https://www.google.co.in";

Please pass the value of providerAccountId for siteAccountId.